# Centre list items

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to centre list items on a page using CSS? I have a long dynamic list of images that repeat in the following fashion:

```
<ul class="imgSelec">
   <li><A href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
   <li><A href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
   <li><A href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
   <li><A href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
   <li><A href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
   <li><A href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
   <li><A href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Each image is 120px wide with 5px padding. The list will be displayed on a variety of mobile devices with different screen widths, so the list will wrap in most cases. I would like the images to be centre aligned on the page but I'm not sure how to go about this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.imgSelec ul li {
    width: 130px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Note: MUST set a width to then use margin: auto to center elements.